# DNS Port Forward Centos 7

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, iptables, port-forwarding

how i can have this config?

- Server A --> use `Server B` ip as nameserver in /etc/resolve.conf
- Server B --> forward all req on port 53 to `Server C:53` using iptables
- Server C --> resolve incoming dns queries

`Server B` iptables config:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination Server_C:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination Server_C:53
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

but now i get timeout in server A dns queries

Comment: why not use on b a Nameserver that query c only? it makes more sense to me. but why you chaining these servers?

Comment: Server C is blocking in my country . but i can access Server C From Server B
i want all my Clients use server B as nameserver then server B use Server C to resolve queries

Comment: and why do you think that a port redirection is the best way to go? in the same manner you could basically setup a vpn on port 443. but we are not allowed to support breaking the law

Comment: if you have any suggestion i am open to hear that . i simply explain the that i think is right if you have better way to do that please explain .

Comment: breaking the law  ? dude i am in iran ! the government block internet access and people stock in iran . i am helping my people to access internet